# Disable / override anchor jump from a popstate event in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, html5-history

This is driving me crazy.
If you have navigation with anchors on the same page, when popstate is invoked, the browser will naturally take you back/forward to the location of that link in your history.

It would be assumed that you could disable the hash jump from happening as you would in a click event via e.preventDefault(); - but that has not been the case thus far.

In most modern browsers, I have been able to hack an override by storing something like $(window).scrollTop(); in a variable and calling it back inside the popstate: $window.scrollTop(somevar);

However in Safari, this workaround causes a quick blip or flash of the original anchor location before relocation to the specified scrollTop - which makes it a non solution

After trying various ideas, it seems that the only way to achieve what I need is to find a way to make Safari treat those anchors the way Chrome or FF does, or somehow disable them entirely on a popstate idea.

Here's sample of the previously mentioned override (works in chrome, FF etc)

```
var scrollY;

$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    scrollY = $window.scrollTop();
});

$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
    // some other page location, not the history #hash
    $(window).scrollTop(scrollY);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

From what I could tell there was no obvious way to accomplish this, so I spent my time on a work around method. Rather than attempting to stop the hash, I was able to achieve the desired effect by temporarily giving the container position fixed + current scroll position then removing the adjustment after the page transition function was complete.

```
var scrollY;

$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    scrollY = $window.scrollTop();
});

$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
    $(window).scrollTop(scrollY);
    $('.container').css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '-'scrollY+'px'
    });
    yourFunction(); // contains animation sequence / css removal
});
```